# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str for some JSONs but not all?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.6

I'm trying to import `id` from a JSON file but square brackets at the start/end of the JSON file for the 2nd JSON cause it to break. Here is the code I currently have to get `id` from json files:

```
import requests

url = 'http://benbotfn.tk:8080/api/cosmetics/search'

params = dict(
    displayName='renegade raider',
)

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = resp.json() # Check the JSON Response Content documentation below

json_id = data['id']

print(json_id)
```

> This code works for any JSONs that don't start/end square brackets.

But when I change the JSON url to: `http://benbotfn.tk:8080/api/cosmetics/search/multiple` and run the same code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apigrabber.py", line 12, in <module>
    json_id = data['id']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

To try and fix this, I tried to convert `data` to a string so that I can remove the square bracket by using this code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://benbotfn.tk:8080/api/cosmetics/search/multiple'

params = dict(
    displayName='renegade raider',
)

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = resp.json() # Check the JSON Response Content documentation below

nosquares = str(data).replace('[','').replace(']','')
json_id = nosquares['id']

print(nosquares)
```

But I then get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apigrabber.py", line 13, in <module>
    json_id = nosquares['id']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is there anyway I can fix the initial error `(list indices must be integers or slices, not str)` without converting it to a string?

print(data) as requested (raw):

```
[{"displayName":"Renegade Raider","backendType":"AthenaCharacter","icon":"http://benbotfn.tk:7071/static/AthenaCharacter/cid_028_athena_commando_f.png","description":"Rare renegade raider outfit.","backendRarity":"EFortRarity::Rare","gameplay_tags":["Cosmetics.Source.Season1.SeasonShop","Cosmetics.Set.StormScavenger","Cosmetics.UserFacingFlags.HasVariants"],"variants":{"STYLE":[{"name":"DEFAULT","icon":"http://benbotfn.tk:7071/static/CosmeticVariants/Game/UI/Foundation/Textures/Icons/Heroes/Athena/Soldier/T-Soldier-HID-028-Athena-Commando-F.T-Soldier-HID-028-Athena-Commando-F.png"},{"name":"CHECKERED","icon":"http://benbotfn.tk:7071/static/CosmeticVariants/Game/UI/Foundation/Textures/Icons/Heroes/Variants/T-Variant-F-RenegadeRaider-Variant.T-Variant-F-RenegadeRaider-Variant.png"}]},"id":"CID_028_Athena_Commando_F","type":"Outfit","rarity":"Rare"}]
```

print(data) - as requested (formatted):

```
[
   {
      "displayName":"Renegade Raider",
      "backendType":"AthenaCharacter",
      "icon":"http://benbotfn.tk:7071/static/AthenaCharacter/cid_028_athena_commando_f.png",
      "description":"Rare renegade raider outfit.",
      "backendRarity":"EFortRarity::Rare",
      "gameplay_tags":[
         "Cosmetics.Source.Season1.SeasonShop",
         "Cosmetics.Set.StormScavenger",
         "Cosmetics.UserFacingFlags.HasVariants"
      ],
      "variants":{
         "STYLE":[
            {
               "name":"DEFAULT",
               "icon":"http://benbotfn.tk:7071/static/CosmeticVariants/Game/UI/Foundation/Textures/Icons/Heroes/Athena/Soldier/T-Soldier-HID-028-Athena-Commando-F.T-Soldier-HID-028-Athena-Commando-F.png"
            },
            {
               "name":"CHECKERED",
               "icon":"http://benbotfn.tk:7071/static/CosmeticVariants/Game/UI/Foundation/Textures/Icons/Heroes/Variants/T-Variant-F-RenegadeRaider-Variant.T-Variant-F-RenegadeRaider-Variant.png"
            }
         ]
      },
      "id":"CID_028_Athena_Commando_F",
      "type":"Outfit",
      "rarity":"Rare"
   }
]
```

Comment: "start/end square brackets" means you're operating on a list, not a dict. And while you can use strings as the keys to a dictionary, you can't use a string to index into a list.

Comment: Your problem is that `type(json.loads('[1,2,3]'))` is list not dict so `[1,2,3]['key']` raises the type error that you're seeing

Comment: Should I convert the list into a library then? @geckos

Comment: You must know that response you're receiving, which is confusing right now, put a `print(data)` so that we know what we're dealing with

Comment: sure adding it now!

Comment: just added, raw & formatted print(data)'s.

Answer (score 1):

When you are receiving list, you will have to fetch the `id` by parsing the list(which depends on what list you are getting), so the code flow should be like this:

```
....
data = resp.json()
if isinstance(data, dict):
    id = data['id']
else:
    # In this case you are getting list of dictionaries so you
    # may get multiple id's.
    # Response shared by you has only one dictionary in list.
    for d in data:  # Iterate over all dict in list
        print(d['id'])
....
```

You can collect all id's in some list/set and use later in program, depending on your requrement.

Comment: http://benbotfn.tk:8080/api/cosmetics/search/multiple?displayName=renegade%20raider

Comment: ^ is the list response.

Comment: Thanks for sharing list response, I have updated my answer to consider list response also, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088089/7486436